# JUnit Mocking Bean which is @autowired with userdefined Annotation

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I have a user defined annotation class as follows.

```
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Message
{
   Dest value();

   public static enum Target { DEFAULT, TEST }
}
```

I use this annotation in the following way.

```
@Component
public class ProcessorBean implements Processor
{

   @Autowired @Message(Message.Target.DEFAULT) Producer<Object, Object> messageProducer;

   @Autowired
   MessageConfig messageConfig;
```

Not sure, how to create a bean of ProcessorBean and inject Producer.

```
@Bean(name="DEFAULT")
        public Producer<Object, Object> producer() {
            return mock(Producer.class);
        }
```

I tried the above one and it is throwing dependency error.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of your `@Message` annotation? What do you want to accomplish when you annotate a field with your `@Message` annotation?

Comment: Hi, That's for some other reason and I just renamed for posting purpose. Just trying to understand if this can be injected for unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Hope, this will be helpful for others.

```
@Message(Message.Target.DEFAULT)
        @Bean
    public Producer<Object, Object> producer() {
        return mock(Producer.class);
    }
```